# Is there a way to stream line this if-elif-else chain? (Python beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

First post on here and it's not so much as a problem because I get the output I want but I'm just curious if there is a simpler way to go about it. Keep in mind too that I am a beginner with python (I'm using python 3) and I'm really enjoying it, this is strictly a curiosity post.

So the exercise I am working on requires you to create an if-elif-else chain to loop through numbers 1-9 and add the appropriate suffix at the end (st,rd,nd..etc) then print them on line at a time. This is what I came up with.

```
ordinalNumbers = range(1,10)

for ordinalNumber in ordNumbers:
    if ordinalNumber == 1:
        print(str(ordinalNumber) + "st")
    elif ordinalNumber == 2:
        print(str(ordinalNumber) + "nd")
    elif ordinalNumber == 3:
        print(str(ordinalNumber) + "rd")
    else:
        print(str(ordinalNumber) + "th")
```

Like I said this gives me the output I'm looking for, just wondering if there was a less repetitive way to go about it. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 2):

Look for what is duplicated in each case: the calls to `str(ordinalNumber)` and `print`. What the `if` statement really does is select the correct suffix to use:

```
for ordinalNumber in ordNumbers:
    if ordinalNumber == 1:
        suffix = "st"
    elif ordinalNumber == 2:
        suffix = "nd"
    elif ordinalNumber == 3:
        suffix = "rd"
    else:
        suffix = "th"

    print(str(ordinalNumber) + suffix)
```

Many times, you can replace the `if` statement altogether with a suitable `dict` lookup. The appropriate `dict` is easier to see after the previous refactoring.

```
suffixes = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}
for ordinalNumber in ordNumbers:
    print(str(ordinalNumber) + suffixes.get(ordinalNumber, "th"))
```

One might consider a nested conditional expression instead, but I'm not terribly fond of it myself.

```
    print(str(ordinalNumber) + "st" if ordinalNumber == 1 else
                               "nd" if ordinalNumber == 2 else
                               "rd" if ordinalNumber == 3 else
                               "th")
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there is a better one, but here is a less repetitive solution

```
ordinalNumbers = range(1,10)
suffixes = ["", "st", "nd", "rd"]

for ordinalNumber in ordinalNumbers:
    print(str(ordinalNumber), end="")
    print(suffixes[ordinalNumber]) if ordinalNumber < 4 else print("th")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
suffix = ('st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th')
print([str(i) + suffix[min(i-1,3)] for i in range(1,10)])
```

outputs:

```
['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th', '8th', '9th']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to store representation mappings like this:

```
ordinalNumbers = range(1, 10)
mapper = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}

for ordinalNumber in ordinalNumbers:
    if ordinalNumber % 10 <= 3:
        print(str(ordinalNumber) + mapper[ordinalNumber])
    else:
        print(str(ordinalNumber) + 'th')
```

This would work for any range of numbers